# How to clone a java TreeModel?

Tags: java, swing, clone, jtree, treemodel

I want to have 2 `TreeModels`: the root of the second `TreeModel` is a node of the first `TreeModel` (therefore, the second `TreeModel` is a subtree of the first `TreeModel`).

I think that I can easily do this by cloning the this `TreeModel` and changing the root. However, I don't know if there is an easy way of cloning `TreeModel`.

Comment: just my curiosity are you want to clone/copy DefaultTreeModel or AbstractTreeModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default implementation of the interface `TreeModel` is `DefaultTreeModel`, which you can easily use here to *instantiate* a subtree model:

```
TreeModel main = ...;
// parent and index have to be defined
TreeNode node = (TreeNode)main.getChild(parent, index);
TreeModel sub = new DefaultTreeModel(node);
```